# Endpoint update very slow when shutdown a node

Tags: kubernetes

When I run `shutdown -h now` command to shutdown a node in kubernetes cluster, endpoint update its state after about 40 seconds, but when I run command `kubectl delete pod POD-NAME`, endpoint update its state very quick. Can anyone explain why?

Comment: Can you share more details regarding your cluster? Where it is located? How many pods per node? What's running there? Can you show an example?

Comment: Whit "shutdown", do you mean "drain"? ...graceful shutdown or immediate?

Comment: @Jonas "shutdown" mean I login to server and run 'shutdown -h now' command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution from [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/97112):

> It may be caused by that the node is marked as NotReady after a grace
> period. This is configurable. After that, pod will be terminating and
> rescheduled
>
> --node-monitor-grace-period duration     Default: 40s
> Amount of time which we allow running Node to be unresponsive before marking it unhealthy. Must be N times more than kubelet's nodeStatusUpdateFrequency, where N means number of retries allowed for kubelet to post node status.
>
> refer to: https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/command-line-tools-reference/kube-controller-manager/

When I change the value of `--node-monitor-grace-period` to `10s`, endpoint update its state more quick.

Answer (score 3):

When you "shutdown" a node, you should do it gracefully with [kubectl drain](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/safely-drain-node/). This will evict the pods in a controlled manner and this should be more friendly to your traffic.

The article [Kubernetes best practices: terminating with grace](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/gcp/kubernetes-best-practices-terminating-with-grace) has a detailed description on all steps that happen when a Pod is *gracefully* terminated. For all planned maintenance, use gracefully shutdown - for unplanned maintenance you can not do much.